# Reusable TextView instead of copy-paste(without include and without style)

Tags: android, xml, textview

In my current project I have about 10 buttons that are almost the same. I'm looking for a way to reuse the code for these buttons.

I've tried to move part of code to separate layout and reuse it via `<include... layout=...>`, but no success.

I use binding in the project and the compiler does not allow me to cast this `View` to `TextView` for calling it from the code. I've tried to move part of this code and set it as a style. No way :-( I have a few selectors here (for different states including enabled and disabled). However, they don't work.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_next_button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    style="@style/Myfont_Bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_button_next_bg"
    android:drawablePadding="36dp"
    android:letterSpacing="-0.01"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_15"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textColor="@drawable/selector_button_next_font"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_16"
                        
    app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/selector_button_next_arrow"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_switchers"/>
```

Any ideas?

I don't want to copy-paste this code 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

Create a style for reused styled Views and apply it in every layout it used

```
<style name="MyCustomStyle" parent="DesiredParentStyleFromLibrary">
    <item name="attribute1">value</item>
    <item name="attribute2">value</item>
    <item name="attribute2">value</item>
// and so on
</style>
```

Comment: I've tried to move part of this code and set it as a style - no way :-(
I have few selectors here(for different states - enabled and disabled) - and they don't work with style